# How to configure angular and vuejs dockerized applications with NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I am having a tough time configuring my second application to run. My client side works perfectly but I can not get my admin application created with vuejs to run.

I have nginx config serving my client application and a second nginx config serving my admin
application. How can I configure my admin application to point to admin
When I try accessing it, it redirects me to http://admin:8000/admin/ instead of localhost:8000

```
admin
FROM node:alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 8000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir -p /admin/html
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /admin/html

server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        root /admin/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Main Nginx config

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream admin {
    server admin:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location /admin {
        rewrite /admin/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://admin;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGinx apply priority on the config, mean that your "/" is working like a wildcard, nothing after "location /" will be reach.

Try this

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream admin {
    server admin:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    location /admin { # <-- this first
        rewrite /admin/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://admin;
    }

    location / { # <-- always at the end, behave as wilcard
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }
}
```